# Python webbrowser library

Tags: python

I happened run into a Python standard library, [<webbrowser>](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html). I tried the example there, and it opened up a new browser and went to the page I wanted. However, there is isn't any further extra functions from the package, like close, switch tab, etc.

```
python -m webbrowser -t "http://www.python.org"
```

Is that all the library does or it is just me underestimating the true power of this package?

Comment: All it does is run a command. If you want fine browser control, use Selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's all it does. To do more, you want to look at something like [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between tabs using pyautogui module

```
pyautogui.keydown('ctrl') 
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.keyup('ctrl')
```